# How can i find a view in a non-activity class?

Tags: android

I want to find a ToggleButton in a non-activity class ,but i get a nullpointerException .i did like next code:

```
public class ClassMode{
    public static boolean isClassMode(Context c) {
    ToggleButton t = new ToggleButton(c);
    t = (ToggleButton) t.findViewById(R.id.classmode);
    if (t.isChecked()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

 public static void setNextMode(final Context context){
   if（isClassMode){
        dosomething();
    }
  }
}
```

did i make anything wrong? i am a new progromer,i suppose this question maybe nothing.but for me is in contrary.
  Anybody help me ,please!Looking forward for your reply.
 3Q!

Comment: Please post the LogCat extract that shows the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` will find a view within the object you call it on. Usually it's called on an activity, but can also be called on any `ViewGroup` that has children.

On your case, you call it on a `Button` object. I doubt this button contains a child with id `R.id.classmode`.

Try:

```
c.findViewById(R.id.classmode)
```

(Note: you should post a LogCat with the actual exception you're getting, else we're only guessing)

Comment: Thanks so much.i maybe know why.

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
t = (ToggleButton) t.findViewById(R.id.classmode);
```

to

```
t = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.classmode);
```